# Count regex matches in one column by values in another column with pandas

Tags: python, regex, pandas, dataframe

I am working with pandas and have a dataframe that contains a list of sentences and people who said them, like this:

```
 sentence                 person
 'hello world'              Matt
 'cake, delicious cake!'    Matt
 'lovely day'               Maria
 'i like cake'             Matt
 'a new day'                Maria
 'a new world'              Maria
```

I want to count non-overlapping matches of regex strings in `sentence` (e.g. `cake`, `world`, `day`) by the `person`. Note each row of `sentence` may contain more than one match (e.g `cake`):

```
person        'day'        'cake'       'world'
Matt            0            3             1
Maria           2            0             1
```

So far I am doing this:

```
rows_cake = df[df['sentences'].str.contains(r"cake")
counts_cake = rows_cake.value_counts()
```

However this `str.contains` gives me rows containing `cake`, but not individual instances of `cake`.

I know I can use `str.counts(r"cake")` on `rows_cake`. However, in practise my dataframe is extremely large (> 10 million rows) and the regexes I am using are quite complex so I am looking for a more efficient solution if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should first try to get the sentence itself and then use `re` to do your optimized regex stuff like that:

```py
for row in df.itertuples(index=False):
   do_some_regex_stuff(row[0], row[1])#in this case row[0] is a sentence. row[1] is person
```

As far as I know itertuples is quiet fast (Notes no.1 [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iterrows.html#pandas.DataFrame.iterrows)). So the only optimization problem you have is with regex itself.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with rather simple solution. But cant claim it to be the fastest or efficient.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# to be used with read_clipboard()
'''
sentence    person
'hello world'   Matt
'cake, delicious cake!' Matt
'lovely day'    Maria
'i like cake'   Matt
'a new day' Maria
'a new world'   Maria
'''

df = pd.read_clipboard()
# print(df)
```

Output:

```
                  sentence person
0            'hello world'   Matt
1  'cake, delicious cake!'   Matt
2             'lovely day'  Maria
3            'i like cake'   Matt
4              'a new day'  Maria
5            'a new world'  Maria
```

.

```
# if the list of keywords is fix and relatively small
keywords = ['day', 'cake', 'world']

# for each keyword and each string, counting the occourance
for key in keywords:
    df[key] = [(len(val.split(key)) - 1) for val in df['sentence']]

# print(df)
```

Output:

```
                 sentence person  day  cake  world
0            'hello world'   Matt    0     0      1
1  'cake, delicious cake!'   Matt    0     2      0
2             'lovely day'  Maria    1     0      0
3            'i like cake'   Matt    0     1      0
4              'a new day'  Maria    1     0      0
5            'a new world'  Maria    0     0      1
```

.

```
# create a simple pivot with what data you needed
df_pivot = pd.pivot_table(df, 
values=['day', 'cake', 'world'], 
columns=['person'], 
aggfunc=np.sum).T

# print(df_pivot)
```

Final Output:

```
        cake  day  world
person
Maria      0    2      1
Matt       3    0      1
```

Open to suggestions if this seems to be a good approach especially given the volume of data. Eager to learn.

Answer (score 0):

since this primarily involves strings, I would suggest taking the computation out of Pandas - Python is faster than Pandas in most cases when it comes to string manipulation :

```
#read in data
df = pd.read_clipboard(sep='\s{2,}', engine='python')

#create a dictionary of persons and sentences : 
from collections import defaultdict, ChainMap
d = defaultdict(list)
for k,v in zip(df.person, df.sentence):
    d[k].append(v)


d = {k:",".join(v) for k,v in d.items()}

#search words
strings = ("cake", "world", "day")

#get count of words and create a dict
m = defaultdict(list)
for k,v in d.items():
    for st in strings:
        m[k].append({st:v.count(st)})

res = {k:dict(ChainMap(*v)) for k,v in m.items()}


print(res)
{'Matt': {'day': 0, 'world': 1, 'cake': 3},
 'Maria': {'day': 2, 'world': 1, 'cake': 0}}

output = pd.DataFrame(res).T

       day  world   cake
Matt    0     1     3
Maria   2     1     0
```

test the speeds and see which one is better. it would be useful for me and others as well.

Comment: Thanks! That makes sense. Can ``strings`` also contain a bunch of regexes in this case? Some of the regexes I'm using are very complex.

Comment: Yes, u can, just ensure u will adapt ur regexes to fit.